# Selenium performance

Tags: python, selenium, splinter

I'm using the Python library splinter (built on top of selenium) to do web testing. I found two performance issues which are making by web testing process extremely slow.

1. For some reason, the web driver seems to wait for around 10 seconds before proceeding to the next page view it has in its list. Is there some kind of implicit wait parameter that tells it to wait for that long? Can this be reduced?
2. When I run the process on a headless state (on a virtual machine, using a virtual display), the process also seems to be much slower than when testing locally. The virtual machine is connected to a much faster network than the one I have locally. What I have observed locally is that when I minimize the browser window, the process does indeed slow down for some reason.

Can anyone clarify what may be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

1. You could try to change this parameter for the WebDriver

   driver.selenium.implicitly_wait(default_implicit_wait)
2. Your desktop is much faster then a virtual machine. The GPU is often very slow on the VM. So the more graphics your page hase the slower it is on the VM. I have seen performance issues for these tests with VMWare.

Comment: As per the second point, I'm not loading CSSs nor images. Would the GPU still be a constraint in this case?

Comment: In all spects the VM is slower. We had non gui linux server when testing an API. This was also much slower.